# Invalid argument specification: Positional argument after varargs

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to pass 2 scalar and 2 list variable into user keyword but I got "Invalid argument specification: Positional argument after varargs." Isn't it possible to pass more than one list variable into user keyword?

What I'm trying to:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Sample Case
    Personal Details Page Fill Form    ${firstName}    ${surname}    @{dateofbirth}  @{nextsalarydate}

    *** Keywords ***
Personal Details Page Fill Form
    [Arguments]    ${firstName}    ${surname}    @{dateofbirth}  @{nextsalarydate} 
    Input Text    id = firstName    ${firstName}
    Input Text    id = lastName    ${surname}
    Personal Details Page Select Date of Birth    ${dateofbirth[0]}    ${dateofbirth[1]}    ${dateofbirth[2]}
    Personal Details Page Select Next Salary Date    ${nextsalarydate[0]}    ${nextsalarydate[1]}    ${nextsalarydate[2]}
```

Comment: please update the question with the snippet of code you are trying to execute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you pass more than one list variable into user keyword, you should use '$' for list instead of '@'. Try as below:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Sample Case
     Personal Details Page Fill Form    ${firstName}    ${surname}    ${dateofbirth}  ${nextsalarydate}

*** Keywords ***
Personal Details Page Fill Form
    [Arguments]    ${firstName}    ${surname}    ${dateofbirth}  ${nextsalarydate} 
    Input Text    id = firstName    ${firstName}
    Input Text    id = lastName    ${surname}
    Personal Details Page Select Date of Birth    ${dateofbirth[0]}    ${dateofbirth[1]}    ${dateofbirth[2]}
    Personal Details Page Select Next Salary Date    ${nextsalarydate[0]}    ${nextsalarydate[1]}    ${nextsalarydate[2]}
```